# Why wont my ArrayAdapter display text? (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

I'm having trouble getting the text within arrayAdapter to display the text. The list does show up in the emulator with the colors and such, but the text won't display... I don't have any errors when I run and the Log.i() I have in the ArrayAdapter does print the expected text.

```
public class ListingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {
    final String TAG = "ListingArrayAdapter";

    public ListingArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ParseObject> listings){
        super(context,0,listings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.listing_item, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        final ParseObject listing = getItem(position);
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        holder.body.setText(listing.getString("desc"));
        holder.title.setText(listing.getString("title"));

        Log.i(TAG, "info set" + listing.getString("title"));
        //Logs the title correctly so, the getString() does return text
        return convertView;
    }


    final class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView body;
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBody"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:lines="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the screen output:
[image]

Comment: By the way, the Parse UI library might help. But if the Log statements show the data, then there is something else wrong with code you've not shown

Comment: Any Idea what could be doing it than? I just have 'backend' parse stuff other than the provided code. I haven't really liked the parse documentation so I'll probably not use the ParseUI

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you do see?

Comment: Just curious, what if you removed `android:weightSum="1"`? and the colors?

Comment: @cricket_007 Added

Comment: @cricket_007 Removing the weight did it! Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is logged, you've got some layout issues.

Suggestions:

1. Make sure you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you add to the adapter.
2. You've got two views, but `android:weightSum="1"`, so try removing that.
3. Maybe the text color is being set as the same as the background. Remove the colors.

Comment: the weightSum was my problem